# My code doesn't work after the ball bounces of the top and bottom border and does not return to the centre 0,0 as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pong, python-turtle

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Pong game by @kahsengho')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Paddle a
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()   #This creates an object
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('white')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350,0)

#Function for paddle a
def paddle_a_up() :
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down() :
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

#Keyboard binding for paddle a
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, 'w')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, 's')

#Paddle b
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()   #This creates an object
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('white')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350,0)

#Function for paddle b
def paddle_b_up() :
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down() :
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

#Keyboard binding for paddle b
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, 'Up')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, 'Down')

#ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()   #This creates an object
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

#Main game loop
while True :
    wn.update()
    #Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    #Border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290 :
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -290 :
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390 :
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -390 :
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kahsengho/PycharmProjects/Projects/Turtle module.py", line 73, in <module>
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1808, in setx
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, self._position[1]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2761, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Answer (score 1):

The top and bottom border logic seems to be working but this is a glitch:

```
if ball.ycor() < -390 :
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1
```

You're testing the y coordinate against an x boundary.  This should be `ball.xcor()`.  A rework of your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Function for paddle a
def paddle_a_up():
    paddle_a.sety(paddle_a.ycor() + 20)

def paddle_a_down():
    paddle_a.sety(paddle_a.ycor() - 20)

# Function for paddle b
def paddle_b_up():
    paddle_b.sety(paddle_b.ycor() + 20)

def paddle_b_down():
    paddle_b.sety(paddle_b.ycor() - 20)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Pong game")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

# Paddle a
paddle_a = Turtle()
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('white')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.setx(-350)

# Keyboard binding for paddle a
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, 's')

# Paddle b
paddle_b = Turtle()
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('white')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.setx(350)

# Keyboard binding for paddle b
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, 'Down')

# ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()

ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

screen.listen()

# Main game loop
while True:
    x, y = ball.position()

    x += ball.dx
    y += ball.dy

    # Border checking
    if y > 290:
        y = 290
        ball.dy *= -1
    elif y < -290:
        y = -290
        ball.dy *= -1

    if not -390 <= x <= 390:
        x, y = (0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    # Move the ball
    ball.setposition(x, y)

    screen.update()
```

Once you get your paddles to hit the ball back and forth, you'll want to consider switching this from `while True:`, which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle, to a timer event via `ontimer()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @cdlane's amazing answer, I would like to say that the ball moves SUPER fast. This isn't good when you are trying to debug, or just play the game in general.

I barely edited your code, and it's now playable.

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Function for paddle a
def paddle_a_up():
    paddle_a.sety(paddle_a.ycor() + 20)

def paddle_a_down():
    paddle_a.sety(paddle_a.ycor() - 20)

# Function for paddle b
def paddle_b_up():
    paddle_b.sety(paddle_b.ycor() + 20)

def paddle_b_down():
    paddle_b.sety(paddle_b.ycor() - 20)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Pong game")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

# Paddle a
paddle_a = Turtle()
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('white')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.setx(-350)

# Keyboard binding for paddle a
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, 's')

# Paddle b
paddle_b = Turtle()
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('white')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.setx(350)

# Keyboard binding for paddle b
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, 'Down')

# ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()

ball.dx = 0.1
ball.dy = 0.1

screen.listen()

# Main game loop
while True:
    x, y = ball.position()

    x += ball.dx
    y += ball.dy

    # Border checking
    if y > 290:
        y = 290
        ball.dy *= -1
    elif y < -290:
        y = -290
        ball.dy *= -1

    if not -390 <= x <= 390:
        x, y = (0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    # Move the ball
    ball.setposition(x, y)

    screen.update()
```

Hope this helps you in any way!